# Robust central stop in harsh conditions

Tags: constant-current, industrial

There is 5 kilometers long cable with numerous (possibly many) central stop buttons in series. The cable is laid around machinery and other cabling at a production plant. The buttons are SPST-NC (normally closed).

As it usually is with production plants it can never stop unless somebody actually pushed the button.

The problem is to design interface at the terminals of the cable that will detect the central stop request. The solution must be sufficiently robust so no false detection occurs during lifetime of the device and, as usually, one needs to keep the costs as low as possible.

How would you solve this? My take is described below.

I use a current-sensing loop. There is current source that feeds the cable with constant current (10mA) from one end and a shunt resistor connected to an ADC at the other end.

The ADC is connected via passive, first order low-pass filter. The microcontroller implements high-order numerical low-pass filter (NRDF type) with settling time of about 75ms. The protection circuitry includes transils and filtering capacitors.

Comment: You are making a safety system too complicated, and adding unnecessary points of failure.  Just have the current through all the stop buttons hold in a relay.

Comment: Presumably false detection is better than false *non*detection, provided it doesn't occur too frequently (in which case the whole system may be worthless).

Comment: Also, what harsh conditions?

Comment: @PeterBennett holding a relay permanently was my first thought too (not only that it is simple, but it is also self-diagnostic), but according to practitioners I asked it about this is not the way - false positives are rare, but not rare enough.

Comment: @immibis both false positives and negatives are equally important. Keep in mind that false detection can cause the plant to stop anytime, which must not happen - these plants run 24/7 and any failure of such kind is costly.

Comment: @student That's why I said "provided they don't occur too frequently". If, say, the plant mistakenly shuts down twice per year, that's better than potentially killing two people per year. (I guess that depends on what kind of machinery this is controlling)

Comment: @immibis Yes, but take "not too frequently" as never. Imagine that you sell this device, which is guaranteed to not fail (it is in fact required). Then, every time the plant is shut down due to this kind of failure, you will be the one to pay the losses..

Comment: If you are getting false stops due to dirty switch contacts or poor cable connections, you should fix those problems, rather than hiding the symptoms.

Comment: Obviously the "do not kill" sort of constraint is implicit. It is not much of a problem, in fact, since it is always easier to verify non-existence of the signal rather than the opposite.

Comment: Why not implement a delay, for example, use the circuit to keep a DC relay energized with a capacitor across the relay. One must hold the button for at least half a second (or whatever) for the capacitor to discharge and the relay to disconnect.

Comment: @Pentium100 : how long does it take for a machine to kill you? Or rip off a limb? Or what happens if it pulls you away from the red button?

Comment: The first thing you need is to do a full safety analysis, and determine the safety catagories you need to meet for various sections.  In general though, at least in the US and Europe, the series single wire E-STOP string is not used any longer for human protection.  Category 2 and higher systems must perform self-checks on all safety devices, and are now the standards for human safety.  This really cannot be handled here.

Comment: @BrianDrummond then make it so that the button has to be always pressed, so if the machine pulls you away from it the button disconnects and the machine stops. If we presume that there is noise in the circuit (after shielding the cables etc) and cannot have any false positives (which you can have with just a relay according to OP) then some averaging has to be done. Maybe not 500ms, but 200ms or whatever.